# Elements fixed + zooming in/out in the browser

Tags: php, html, css, fixed

I need some help regarding my little css code. I want all my elements to be still in the stage of zooming in and zooming out in the browser.

I would appreciated a little tweak in my code.

The CSS Code:

```
form{
    position:absolute;

    top:270px;
    right:490px;
}
  input{

  }

ul{

    margin-top: 330px;
    padding-left: 410px;
}

li{

    padding:10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display:inline;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: "Lucida Console";
   }



h4{
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 1115px;
    margin-top: -220px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

Index code:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Pogo++</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="search.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v11/2UX7WLTfW3W8TclTUvlFyQ.woff">
  </head>

  <body>

   <center>
   <a href="search.php"> <img src="pogo++.jpg" width="510px" height="auto"> </a>
   </center>

   <form action = "search.php" method="get">

   Pogo: <input type="text" name="value" placeholder="Search Anything" style="height:40px; width:240px;"  >
   <input type="submit" name="search" value="Pogo It" style="height:40px">

   </form>

 <?php
   $con=oci_connect('system','system','localhost/XE');
     if(isset($_GET['search'])){



     $stid = oci_parse($con, 'SELECT * FROM search');
     oci_execute($stid);
       while($row=oci_fetch_array($stid)){
          $title = $row['title'];
          $link = $row['sitelink1'];
          $desc = $row['sitedesk1'];

     echo $title;

       }
     }
?>

  <a href=#><h4>&copy 2014 Pogosoft</h4></a>

   </body>

<footer>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="conditions.php">Conditions and Terms</a></li>
  <li><a href="conf.php">Confidentiality</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
   </html>
```

Comment: Why are you making the form position absolute ?, this will not let the form to be in the stage in all window size (or zoomings)

Comment: i see. so i just adjust that line of code from position :absolute to fixed? Cause i tried that too and it didn't work that way.

Comment: Yes I think, or if you want it to be centred and have an absolute position, you have to give it top and left position with percentage (50%, 50% for centering) and give it margin-top = (form height / 2) and margin-left = (form height / 2) which I recommend you JS for that

Comment: try to zoom in/out the frontpage of google. That's what i mean all the elements are sitting in their place. I want to obtain the same effect.

Comment: I tried , and not all the elements are sitting in their place,

Comment: you have to make a responsive design for that , using percantage for the width and top/left positionning